# C++ Builder 10.3.3 [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Could not open .\Win32\Debug\TabbedApplication.exe (program still running?)

Tags: c++, c++builder, fatal-error

In C++Builder 10.3.3, when running my application, it stops the process and pops up with an error:

> Unable to create process: Access denied

I don't know why this happens, and for the life of me I can't figure out what it is talking about.

I tried to build the solution to see if the error was occurring there, and it appears this is the case. After building the solution, the compiler stops the process and a fatal error pops up:

> [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Could not open.\Win32\Debug\TabbedApplication.exe (program still running?)

Does anyone know what this error means, and how to fix it?

Comment: It means someone likely has an open handle to your EXE file that is blocking access to the file. You can use [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find out who exactly.

Comment: It means that it can't create a new copy of your executable because the existing file is in use and can't be overwritten. Task Manager or ProcExplorer (as @RemyLebeau suggested) will help you find out what has it open.

Comment: It could be your antivirus or it could still be running from your last debug

Comment: [How do you find what process is holding a file open in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/)

Answer (score 0):

I added a new target platform in my project in the right
I added windows 64 bit and it worked
hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I've been getting this messages for months (even with previous verions of RAD studio) and i haven't found a solution yet.

I have used a process explorer and the process is not running but if i close and reopen the IDE the file is not locked anymore.

So i think the problem it's related with the "debugger" that stills is locking the file even when the IDE stopped the debugging process.

I have tried even the "unlocker" utility but it doesn't detect any process is locking the file ...

For know we have to wait until the debugger release the file.

Comment: Not the debugger, it is the installed anti-malware product that does this on your machine.  The crapware does not deal well with an executable file suddenly appearing from seemingly no-where.  Get rid of it.

Comment: I have only installed the Defender antivirus and i have disabled the "real time" option of th antivirus and also i have added the executable to the list of exclusions in the Defender options ... so is not the anti virus ...

Comment: Hi, why answering of you have no solution? Please edit your question instead telling what you already tried.

Comment: Please quit posting answers that don't answer the question. The answer section is for solutions to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

These is the configuration i have tried in the registry:

HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Debugging\Embarcadero Debuggers\Evaluators

[dedfault]    REG_SZ   dcc32260.dll
com32x.dll    REG_SZ   -1
dcc32260.dll  REG_SZ   0

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?